Why can I not (or how to) programmatically access content of GVFS-provided URI?
Problem Summary
On its own, the “Context”-headed section below would be a question for Stack Overflow. However, upon further diagnosis, I've ascertained that I appear to be utterly unable to access the applications:/ URI outside of Dolphin, via the CLI:

CLI (gio)
gio list -l applications:/

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart/Documents/webpage_frontend> gio list -l applications:/                                                     
gio: applications:/: Operation not supported


Dolphin



Why is this so? To my knowledge, this should be accessible as a virtual mount via the GVFS subsystem. However, it doesn't appear to be mounted:
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart/Documents/webpage_frontend> gio mount -l              
Mount(0): s11vzd -> file:///run/media/RokeJulianLockhart/s11vzd
  Type: GUnixMount

There isn't even a directory for them:
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart/Documents/webpage_frontend> tree "$Env:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs"
/run/user/1000/gvfs  [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files

I presume I must be doing something incorrectly. However, I've been unable to ascertain what.
Context
I'm trying to create a .JS file that outputs the content of applications:/ (accessible via KDE's Dolphin and GNOME's Nautilus file managers) to a .HTML file, so that I can render it in the Web Browser KDE Plasma 6 plasmashell plasmoid. However, when I connect to the server (at http://localhost:3000/index.html) I see:
<html><head>
    <title>List GVFS Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Files in applications:/</h1>
    <div id="fileList"><ol><li>Error accessing GVFS URI: gio: applications:/: Operation not supported</li></ol></div>

    <script>
        async function fetchFiles() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/list-gvfs-files');
                const fileList = await response.text();

                // Parse and display the file list
                const fileArray = fileList.split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');
                const listContainer = document.getElementById('fileList');
                const list = document.createElement('ol');
                fileArray.forEach(file => {
                    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = file;
                    list.appendChild(listItem);
                });
                listContainer.appendChild(list);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
            }
        }

        fetchFiles();
    </script>


</body></html>

Specifically:

Error accessing GVFS URI: gio: applications:/: Operation not supported

Undermentioned, I've included a copy of the files, if of interest:

server.js
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Serve static files from the current directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/list-gvfs-files', (req, res) => {
    // Check current environment variables
    console.log('Current Environment Variables:', process.env);

    // Run the gio command and capture output for debugging
    exec("gio list -l applications:/", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("Command Error:", error);
            console.error("Standard Error:", stderr);
            return res.status(500).send("Error accessing GVFS URI: " + stderr);
        }

        console.log("Command Output:", stdout);
        res.send(stdout);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});



index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List GVFS Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Files in applications:/</h1>
    <div id="fileList"></div>

    <script>
        async function fetchFiles() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/list-gvfs-files');
                const fileList = await response.text();

                // Parse and display the file list
                const fileArray = fileList.split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');
                const listContainer = document.getElementById('fileList');
                const list = document.createElement('ol');
                fileArray.forEach(file => {
                    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = file;
                    list.appendChild(listItem);
                });
                listContainer.appendChild(list);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
            }
        }

        fetchFiles();
    </script>
</body>
</html>




They've been rather cobbled from what I've located online about similar topics (unfortunately, most discussions about this topic involved PHP, which I'd rather not utilize, because I'm even more unfamiliar with it).

It is not a GIO/GVFS-provided URI. Dolphin is not based around GNOME's GLib2 in any way – it is written using Qt and KDE Frameworks and uses the KDE counterpart, KIO, for providing the virtual mount feature. You might be able to access it using kioclient from outside Qt/KF-based apps.

Thank you! kioclient ls 'applications:/' works for this! I've asked https://discuss.kde.org/t/does-kf-kio-core-udsentry-for-not-found-creating-a-default-one-please-fix-the-kioworker-kio-worker-indicate-a-fault-in-how-im-calling-it/25380?u=rokejulianlockhart to ascertain how to utilize it correctly. I was originally under the assumption that GVFS was one of myriad initially GNOME-specific standards that became a FreeDesktop one, and thus assumed that Plasma would use it too.
